# python-try block does the same thing whether the condition it's false or true

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
try:

    condition1==True
    condition2==True
    condition2==True
    print("ok")
except:
       print("no")
```

I am absolutely certain that condition2 is not True but is False. but still i get printed "ok", same thing happens even if i replace `condition2==True` with `condition2==False`

I've tried several times, I've done more tests using other methods. I even thought it might be a bug in the Python version I use because it's absurd.How is it possible? what could this be due to?

EDIT: if I use an IF statement , it works!!!

Comment: None of your statements in the `try` block raise an exception, what exception are you expecting to be raised?

Comment: `try`/`except` is looking for an _Exception_ to be raised, eg. `ValueError`.

Comment: The statements in the try block are booleans, not exceptions. To get except to run, it would be best to throw an error if the conditions aren't true.

Comment: try blocks aren't the same as if blocks.

Comment: condition2 is FALSE not TRUE, so it should go to the except block, or not?

Comment: `False` is not an exception. `False` is a Boolean, which is a perfectly valid, and crucially non-exceptional, value.

Comment: No. These are all individual statements inside the block that evaluate to booleans. The statement `False` on its own doesn't lead to an exception for it to enter the `except` block. If you wanted those statement to raise an error on `False` you could write it as an assertion `assert condition2 == True`

Comment: I thought the try just kept going until it found something False

Comment: Who taught you that?

Answer (score 3):

Python's try-except blocks do not work with conditions like that. Instead, a `try` block will try to execute a piece of code **unless** it runs into some exception along the way. If it does so, the `except` block will be activated and code inside it will be executed.

Essentially: conditions don't matter for try-except blocks.

This is a sample:

```py
a = 100
b = 0
try:
    my_var = a/b
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

try running it, see what error you get!